# How to add "parts" of URL from cells on Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a macro for getting data from web. And having struggle of defining the URL parts.

I would like to make the URL like this and the xxxxx should be the value in G1 cell in the same worksheet:

```
https://sample.com/?ID=xxxxxx
```

Now I have the following codes, and will be happy if could edit for that. How should I edit for URL3 to make it to get the ID number from the G1 cell and how should I build the URL string to make it "URL2+URL3"

Thanks for your helpings.

```
Sub GetData()


Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim URL2 As String
Dim URL3 As String


URL2 = "https://sample.com/?ID="
URL3 = "the ID in G1 cell"

XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
XMLPage.send

HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

ProcessHTMLPage HTMLDoc
End Sub
```

```
Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)

Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer


    Set HTMLTables = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")


    For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
        If HTMLTable.Rows(0).Cells(0).innerText = "Firma Bilgileri" Then
            Range("A29").Value = HTMLTable.className
            Range("B1").Value = Now


            RowNum = 30
            For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                'Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innerText


                ColNum = 1
                For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
                    Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
                    ColNum = ColNum + 1
                Next HTMLCell


                RowNum = RowNum + 1
            Next HTMLRow
        End If
    Next HTMLTable

End Sub
```

Comment: Url needs to be `URL2&url3`where url3=`range("g1").value`

Comment: Solved it! Thanks!